# How to persist shadow of an inner div while drawing as image using canvas?

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas, html2canvas, drawimage

In the UI I am having a div that contains preview text of a blogpost.
[image: sample]

I am trying to maintain the box-shadow while drawing this div element as an image using HTML canvas. How I can achieve that?

Code I am using to draw as image:

```
let scaledElement = document.getElementById("screenRef");
let canvas = await html2canvas(scaledElement);
let croppedCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
let croppedCanvasContext = croppedCanvas.getContext("2d");
let cropPositionTop = 0;
let cropPositionLeft = 0;
let cropWidth = canvas.width;
let cropHeight = canvas.height;
croppedCanvas.width = cropWidth;
croppedCanvas.height = cropHeight;
croppedCanvasContext.drawImage(canvas, cropPositionLeft, cropPositionTop);
let dataUrl = croppedCanvas.toDataURL();
```

And the result I am getting as of now:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I have achieved it.

```
let croppedCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
let croppedCanvasContext = croppedCanvas.getContext("2d"); // init data

let cropPositionTop = CANVAS.OFFSET_POSITION;
let cropPositionLeft = CANVAS.OFFSET_POSITION;
let cropWidth = canvas.width;
let cropHeight = canvas.height;
croppedCanvas.width = cropWidth + CANVAS.PADDING; //for getting space around main image
croppedCanvas.height = cropHeight + CANVAS.PADDING; //for getting space around main image
var grd = croppedCanvasContext.createLinearGradient(
  CANVAS.START_X,
  CANVAS.START_Y,
  croppedCanvas.width,
  croppedCanvas.height
);
grd.addColorStop(colorStop.stop, colorStop.color);
croppedCanvasContext.fillStyle = grd;
croppedCanvasContext.fillRect(
  CANVAS.START_X,
  CANVAS.START_Y,
  croppedCanvas.width,
  croppedCanvas.height
);
croppedCanvasContext.shadowOffsetX = CANVAS.START_X;
croppedCanvasContext.shadowOffsetY = CANVAS.START_Y;
croppedCanvasContext.shadowBlur = CANVAS.SHADOW_BLUR;
croppedCanvasContext.shadowColor = CANVAS.SHADOW_COLOR;
croppedCanvasContext.drawImage(canvas, cropPositionLeft, cropPositionTop);
```